# How can I read and display data from a serial port using ADB shell?

Tags: android, bash, adb

Pardon my google-fu but I am positive nothing very similar was asked before.

I'm new to unix commands, so apologies for my ignorance that maybe displayed.

This is what I have: a custom board running android OS.

This is what I want:

Read data received over the serial port.

Since Android is a Unix-esque, linux-cored, system, I was relying heavily on tutorials about linux system, those bash commands.

By using

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

I was able to decide target port name being "ttyAMA0", the baud rate and other parameters are all correct.

So this is what I did then:

```
cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Nothing happens. I was expecting my screen gets spammed by data received, but nothing.

Was I going the wrong direction at a strategic level or there was some mess-up in detail?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that cat will only capture for a brief moment right after it was called.

So eventually I settled this issue by repeating "cat" commands at a much higher frequency.

Comment: Had you tried tail -f command?